# Apache mod_fcgid keeps giving error

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, drupal, mod-fcgid

I have ubuntu server, PHP 5.3.2,  Apache/2.2.14. and i have drupal website on this server.
whenever i try to upload image using imagemanager drupal module i got the following errors in apache log and dont get my uploaded image as expected:

```
[Sun Mar 27 15:54:07 2011] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/elpis/htdocs/index.php(2178) exit(communication error), get unexpected signal 11
[Sun Mar 27 15:54:25 2011] [warn] [client 95.172.201.81] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: http://ec2.albawaba.com/sites/all/modules/imagemanager/pages/im/index.html
[Sun Mar 27 15:54:25 2011] [warn] [client 95.172.201.81] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function, referer: http://ec2.albawaba.com/sites/all/modules/imagemanager/pages/im/index.html
[Sun Mar 27 15:54:31 2011] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/elpis/htdocs/index.php(2435) exit(communication error), get unexpected signal 11
[Sun Mar 27 15:54:36 2011] [warn] [client 95.172.201.81] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: http://ec2.albawaba.com/sites/all/modules/imagemanager/pages/im/index.html
[Sun Mar 27 15:54:36 2011] [warn] [client 95.172.201.81] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function, referer: http://ec2.albawaba.com/sites/all/modules/imagemanager/pages/im/index.html
[Sun Mar 27 15:54:43 2011] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/elpis/htdocs/index.php(2176) exit(communication error), get unexpected signal 11
[Sun Mar 27 15:55:53 2011] [warn] [client 95.172.201.81] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: http://ec2.albawaba.com/sites/all/modules/imagemanager/pages/im/index.html
[Sun Mar 27 15:55:53 2011] [warn] [client 95.172.201.81] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function, referer: http://ec2.albawaba.com/sites/all/modules/imagemanager/pages/im/index.html
[Sun Mar 27 15:55:55 2011] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/elpis/htdocs/index.php(2440) exit(communication error), get unexpected signal 11
```

any idea is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please, show your config files. All telepathists are on vacation.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to enable PHP error logging.  As an example, you might be exceeding max_input_time, but without the output from the PHP error log, you'll have a heck of a time figuring that out except by trial-and-error.

Comment: i am enabling PHP error log already, but nothing in it!! however, i switched to use worker instead of prefork

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure "signal 11″ is a segmentation fault, which would seem to indicate an invalid memory access attempt. This could be an issue with:

1. Incorrect File/Folder Permissions,
2. Bad Code, or Incorrect Syntax in the .htaccess File, or...
3. Incorrect php.ini Configuration